# Copy part of table with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a large table with data.

The table has a header.

I need to copy exactly the header of that table, from `<thead>` to `</thead>`, into another section within the same document. How can I do that?

```
<table id="myTbl">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    ...
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: To what purpose? A `thead` can only go in one place. Unless you want to copy it to another `table`..?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy elements with [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

> As shown in the discussion for .append(), normally when an element is
>   inserted somewhere in the DOM, it is moved from its old location. So,
>   given the code:
>
> ```
> $('.hello').appendTo('.goodbye');
> ```
>
> The resulting DOM structure would
>   be:
>
> ```
> <div class="container">
>   <div class="goodbye">
>     Goodbye
>     <div class="hello">Hello</div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> To prevent this and instead create a copy of the element, you could write the following:
>
> ```
> $('.hello').clone().appendTo('.goodbye');
> ```

Comment: Brilliant! Never heard of clone() but I believe this is exactly what I need! Thanks.

Comment: @DavidThomas I added the sample from the docs that shows how to copy from one part of the page to another.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.clone` and `prependTo` the desired table

```
$('#myTbl thead').clone().prependTo('<Destination Table>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will copy the header from table with id `tbl1` and put ito to another table with id `tbl2`

```
    var copy=$("#tbl1").find('th').clone();
    $("#tbl2").prepend(copy);
```

Here is the sample http://jsfiddle.net/hmrNN/7/